# How may I use touch gestures to scroll through a series of pictures?

Tags: blackberry

How can I create  a gesture activity in Blackberry in such a way that  images appear one after another on different screens ? Can anybody explain me with an example ? I want the images to appear one after another on the mouse click when dragged from left side as well as right side

Comment: You can use PictureScrollField for the Blackberry 5.0

Comment: I need an answer which is simple and explained step by sep.

Answer (score 2):

There's some sample code for this on the BlackBerry website.

**Create a scrollable image field**

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-scrollable-image-field/ta-p/444955

Also it sounds like you might find this introduction to touch gestures helpful

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Introduction-to-Touch-Gestures/ta-p/555363

Comment: I am new to BlackBerry and was not able to follow what was there in the link.It will be really helpful if anyone could explain me with a simple example

Comment: The link already contains sample code that is very well commented at each step. Either you're having a laugh or you would benefit from some general reading/getting started tutorials before you start asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

use the below code to find the touchGESTURE.

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) 
{
   switch(message.getEvent()) 
   {
      case TouchEvent.GESTURE:
         TouchGesture gesture = message.getGesture();
         switch(gesture.getEvent()) 
         {
           case TouchGesture.NAVIGATION_SWIPE:
             Dialog.alert("Swipe direction: " + gesture.getSwipeDirection()  
             +            ", "
             +            "\nMagnitude: " + gesture.getSwipeMagnitude());
             return true;
         }
   }
   return false;
}
```

for more info visit [Swipe_gestures_trackpad](http://docs.blackberry.com/es-es/developers/deliverables/29251/Swipe_gestures_trackpad_1603027_11.jsp)