# Blackberry swipe left/right gesture

Tags: blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How may I use touch gestures to scroll through a series of pictures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452738/how-may-i-use-touch-gestures-to-scroll-through-a-series-of-pictures)

I want to display array of images one after another by using swipe left or swipe right gesture.Can anybody give me some idea as how to this.A simple example will be really useful.

Comment: how is this question different to others you have asked? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452738/how-may-i-use-touch-gestures-to-scroll-through-a-series-of-pictures